# Prune a tree built from a txt file

Tags: r, tree

I have a txt file, which contains a sequence of numbers like the following:

```
1 1 3 2
2 2 1 1
3 2 3 1
2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1
3 2 3 2
1 1 3 1
2 1 1 1
```

(It is only an example to explain my problem.) Each row, in the file txt, has four positions separated by a space. The first and the third can assume three values: 1, 2 or 3.
The remaining positions can assume only two values: 1 or 2.

Each row represents the path of a tree. The tree consists of a root node and levels of additional nodes that form the hierarchy: the first and the third levels can have three nodes (1, 2 or 3) and so on, as previously described.

Then, the tree described by previous example is the following:

[image]

I would prune the tree as described in the following picture:

[image]

The nodes circled in red must be reduced to just one node, because each node in the circles has only one leaf.

Comment: cool tree, is there an R package you used to create it??

Comment: @lefft, no I used: https://www.draw.io/

Comment: This sounds like a job for *igraph*.

Comment: One solution would be to somehow convert your table into a [newick tree format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format) and then use the excellent R packages available to modify them (e.g. [ape](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/index.html) or [phytools](https://github.com/liamrevell/phytools)) .

Comment: @ThomasGuillerme, thank you. Could you write an example, please? I'm not familiar with trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine which nodes have only one child by looking at every pair of adjacent columns in your table/matrix and observing how many times each number appears next to another. Suppose your data is stored in `mat`:

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    3    2
[2,]    2    2    1    1
[3,]    3    2    3    1
[4,]    2    2    2    2
[5,]    1    1    1    1
[6,]    3    2    3    2
[7,]    1    1    3    1
[8,]    2    1    1    1
```

For the first two columns, we remove all duplicates (i.e., the same subpath) we look at occurrences of each number with its neighbors and count how many distinct paths there are:

```
> table(mat[,c(1,2)][!duplicated(mat[,c(1,2)]),1])
1 2 3 
1 2 1
```

As you can see, 1 has 1 path and so can be pruned, as can 3. Finally, 2 has 2 paths and so we will not prune it.

The next part is tricky, because you'll only want to look at sub-trees (because for example, 1 -> 1 might occur in one part of the tree and 1 -> 2 might occur in another but if they don't share a parent, we might still want to prune them). Something like:

```
table(mat[mat[,newLevel]==newRoot,c(2,3)][!duplicated(mat[mat[,newLevel]==newRoot,c(2,3)]),1])
```

where newLevel is the column of the matrix you are up to and newRoot the value of the node in that level that will be the root of your subtree. For example, using the node in the first level of the tree with value 2 as the root:

```
> table(mat[mat[,1]==2,c(2,3)][!duplicated(mat[mat[,1]==2,c(2,3)]),1])
1 2 
1 2
```

As you can see, it found that 1 should be pruned and 2 should not, for the nodes directly beneath the first 2 node. You would then iterate this through the tree (you could implement it recursively, for example).

Comment: Thank you! Maybe, if newLevel is = 1, c(..) have to be c(1,2) and not c(2,3)? I.e.: table(mat[mat[,newLevel]==newRoot,c(newLevel,newLevel+1)][!duplicated(mat[mat[,newLevel]==newRoot,c(newLevel,newLevel+1)]),1])

Comment: not quite, because newLevel tells you the level of the root of the sub-tree and c(2,3) looks at the path between the first leaves of the sub-tree and the second leaves. You could adjust the process to have it be newLevel=1, c(1,2) but then you'd have to adjust what I've written.